# ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile#read returns empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails app where I'm parsing an uploaded CSV. I just discovered that the parsing has stopped working and am investigating.

I've tracked it back to the fact that I call `.read` on an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, and that returns an empty string.

The uploaded file is not empty, and when I inspect the `UploadedFile` object, it has an attribute like `@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130530-34976-6jaqt5`. If I `cat` that file on the filesystem, it contains what I expect.

**Why might `.read` return an empty string?**

I'm using Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Please post your parsing code.

Comment: @PauloFidalgo - My parsing code starts with `CSV.parse(input_string)` then maps over the returned rows. The problem is that `input_string` is blank, and that's because this call to `read` is blank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Try rewinding

My colleague suggested calling `rewind` before `read`, and that works. Apparently some other code is reading the file first.

### Update

Nobody's reading the file before I am, as far as I can tell. I created an initializer to spy on the `UploadedFile`:

```
# config/initializers/uploaded_file.rb
class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile

  alias_method :old_read, :read
  def read(*args)
    Rails.logger.info "file #{self} is getting read by #{caller.first}!"
    old_read(*args)
  end
end
```

I didn't see any other calls to `read`. Thinking there might be some other method called that would advance the read pointer, I went further and replaced the class entirely:

```
# config/initializers/uploaded_file.rb
ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile = Class.new do

  def initialize(*args)
    Rails.logger.info "initilized with #{args}"
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    Rails.logger.info "file got #{method_name} with #{args}.\
      Block? #{block_given?} caller? #{caller.first}"
  end

end
```

Still nothing. I see a call to `initialize`, my call to `rewind`, and my call to `read`.

Seems like this file comes pre-wound to the end. I'm not sure why that might be, but `rewind` is still the fix for me.

Comment: I ran into the same issue locally (MacOS) but the upload seems to work fine on our linux servers. Rewind worked for me as well.

My first suspicion was that it was Pow as I had recently updated that but it fails in the same way when run through unicorn.

If I discover a smoking gun, I will post here. It is curious that this problem occurred for me suddenly and around the same time as it started for you -- perhaps a recently updated gem is responsible?

Comment: Same weird issue cropped up on me today.  I traced it back using `git-bisect` to a commit from May 30th where I did a `bundle update`.  Unfortunately haven't had time to pick it apart further yet (a lot of gems were updated), but I put the `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle exec gem list` diffs in a gist: https://gist.github.com/abevoelker/5750689

Answer (score 0):

If the file was just uploaded and written, be sure to close it before proceeding. For example:

```
out = File.open(path, 'w')
out.write(stuff)
out.close # omitting this may cause the issue described!
```